# ODP.Net - Calling stored procedure with custom type parameter throws ORA-06550/PLS-00306

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm trying to call a stored procedure that takes a SYS_REFCURSOR output parameter and an input parameter with a custom type. Right now when I try to call the procedure from my application I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_TEST_01'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is the PL/SQL script that creates the custom type and the stored procedure I'm trying to call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR
            SELECT st.*
            FROM TABLE(in_list) t
            JOIN SOME_TABLE st ON st.SOME_COLUMN = t.COLUMN_VALUE;
    END SP_TEST_01;
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/
```

I've messed around with a variety of approaches and iterations on the C# side of things, but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
using (var context = new SomeDbContext())
{
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "TEST_PACKAGE_01.SP_TEST_01";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ArrayBindCount = values.Count; // values is a List<string>

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
        {
            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
            Value = values.ToArray(),
            Size = values.Count
        });

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
        {
            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        });

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
              // do stuff here              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `cmd.ArrayBindCount` is being assigned incorrectly. It doesn't make sense to me that you would set it at the command level, especially if you could have two array parameters with different lengths. Nevertheless, the documentation says that's what it's for.  Maybe you should use `PUSID_SVG_RUSID_FACE_LIST.Count`. I believe the `Size` parameter still refers to the size of the data type (`varchar2` in this case).

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/put-your-arrays-in-a-bind

Comment: @madreflection that was a typo from copy/pasting. `values` is the list that I'm trying to work with. But I tried getting rid of `cmd.ArrayBindCount` and tried with and without the Size parameter, and also tried it with the same value as the length in my custom type; but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Which provider are you using, Oracle.DataAccess, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core?

Comment: @madreflection `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error and I discovered that the [main] problem with passing the array parameter is in the type declaration of `t_string_list`.  You need to make it an indexed array rather than an associative one by adding `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`.  In order to do *that*, you have to move the type definition into the package because that clause doesn't seem to be supported outside of a package.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    TYPE t_string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
```

This at least gets the parameter passed.  Once executing the procedure, however, I got another error in querying the list as a table using the `TABLE()` operator.

> ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677841) says that assigning the list to a temporary variable somehow causes it to work.  Why?  Oracle, I guess.  In all seriousness, though, it may be delay-loaded and assigning it to a temporary causes it to fully read the parameter data.  That's just a working theory, though, and a better solution (with explanation) would be welcomed.

Regardless of why that workaround helped, this worked:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
        temp_list t_string_list := in_list;
    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR
            SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE
            FROM TABLE(temp_list) t;
            -- took out the join for testing
    END SP_TEST_01;
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
```

On the C# side, `cmd.ArrayBindCount` isn't what's advertised, apparently.  I got a nasty error when I assigned it:

> ORA-03137: malformed TTC packet from client rejected: ...

So I got rid of that before digging into the type and procedure definitions and that got me to the error you reported above.  So as far as the parameteter itself, what you had was right.

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
{
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
    Value = values.ToArray()
});
```

The `Count` property is optional but if you assign it a value less than the number of elements you want to pass, it will only pass what you specify.  Best to leave it unassigned.

For an *output* array, however, I'm guessing you would need to set the `Count` property to tell it the maximum number of elements on output *and* `ArrayBindSize` to specify the maximum size of each element.

Simply selecting the array elements into the cursor, as in my even-simpler version of your procedure, I was able to observe each element of the array in `reader[0]` within the `while` loop.

Comment: I think this is getting close, but I'm getting compiler errors in SQL Developer for the second portion of the SQL script. On the line FROM TABLE(temp_list) t; it's saying it can't access rows from a non-nested table item. It also gives an error saying 'expression is of wrong type'. I tried using and not using the temp_list with the same results

Comment: That's strange because I was able to create that procedure just fine, call it from C# (the version with `temp_list`, anyway), and iterate through the results. Have you changed it much? Unfortunately, I'm no expert on Oracle, by far, and that part of it may be out of my depth. I don't use Oracle regularly; I have a local Express (18c) installation for testing a multi-provider library I'm developing. You're on 11g, right? There may be significant functional differences in this area.

Comment: I tried a few different variants without much luck. And yeah, 11g... I've only used Oracle for a few months, but I'm getting the impression that 11g is the Windows Vista of Oracle releases. Things that worked fine in 10g broke in 11g but work on every version after. I'll probably fight with my manager to see if I can implement the unmanaged Oracle driver instead and make a UDT. Fingers Crossed, but I'll give you the check. It's a good solution that other people might find helpful. Especially if they aren't using an ancient version.

Comment: Good analogy. I'm inclined to agree. Not many people are able to compartmentalize problems like that, so I really appreciate that you accepted the answer. For your part, you provided an excellent minimal example, so I upvoted for that.